# In Java how add an interface into an arraylist without creating a seperate class implementing the interface

Tags: java, lambda, interface

I'm having a bit of trouble adding an interface into an arraylist in java. 
What I'm trying to do is:

MyInterface

```
public interface MyInterface
{
    public String string();

    public int integer();
}
```

My method computes a string and an integer and tries to store it as a new instance of this interface. 
I can add a new class that implements the interface and add that to the list.

```
 ArrayList<MyInterface> myList = new ArrayList<>();
    myList.add(new MyInterface()
    {
        @Override
        public String string()
        {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public int integer()
        {
            return null;
        }
    });
```

I know I can do it like in the above code, but I would like to do it in a more elegant way. Perhaps using **lambda** expressions to achieve this?

Comment: Your `MyInterface` isn't a functional interface and cannot be used with lambdas

Comment: `myList.add( (MyInterface) null)` ?

Comment: functional interfaces **Must** have only **one** abstract method, hence this cannot be turned into _lambda expression_

Comment: You can still add default methods to the functional interface but true, one abstract method allowed.

Comment: I dont see how adding instances of an anyomous inner class to a list could be considered to be *elegant*. Ever.

Comment: In other words: you rather step back and explain the problem you intend to solve here. Because your "solution" ... sounds more like a problem, than a solution to anything.

Comment: If you only have two values, you might want to use `Map.Entry`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since only functional interfaces can be implemented via lambda expressions, you can’t use them to implement your interface without changing it. An interface which basically represents a storage of two values is not an intended use case for lambda expressions, so while it is possible to change the interface in a way that makes it possible, the result is not really a win in comprehensibility:

```
public interface MyInterface {
    public default String string() {
        return (String)process((s,i)->s);
    }
    public default int integer() {
        return (int)process((s,i)->i);
    }
    Object process(BiFunction<String,Integer,?> f);
}
```

Allows to create a `[{"foo", 42}, {"bar", 100}]` list without an explicit implementation type via

```
List<MyInterface> list=Arrays.asList(f -> f.apply("foo", 42), f -> f.apply("bar", 100));
System.out.println(list.get(0).string()+", "+list.get(0).integer());
System.out.println(list.get(1).string()+", "+list.get(1).integer());
```

though it would be much clearer to have an ordinary inner class in one factory method:

```
public interface MyInterface
{
    public String string();
    public int integer();
    public static MyInterface of(String s, int i) {
        return new MyInterface() {
            @Override public String string() { return s; }
            @Override public int integer() { return i; }
        };
    }
}
```

usable as

```
List<MyInterface> list=Arrays.asList(MyInterface.of("foo", 42),MyInterface.of("bar", 100));
System.out.println(list.get(0).string()+", "+list.get(0).integer());
System.out.println(list.get(1).string()+", "+list.get(1).integer());
```

(The naming of the factory method becomes much clearer when you change the interface’s name to something meaningful; even if its something generic like `Tuple.of("foo", 42)`)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use lambda here because `MyInterface` is no functional interface. But you can create a simple class implementing this interface. Pass the computed values via constructor and you can add the new instance in a single line like

```
myList.add(new MyImpl(s, i));
```

I think you will get the code of `MyImpl` by yourself :)

Answer (score 1):

If your interface has 2 methods, then it's not a *functional interface*, so you cannot use a lambda that matches its type. Functional interfaces **must have only one abstract method**, as per the spec.

However, if you don't want to create a class for this, you don't need to. The JDK already offers an interface and a class that implements it that suit your needs: the [`Map.Entry`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html) interface and the [`AbstractMap.SimpleEntry`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/AbstractMap.SimpleEntry.html) class. You could use them this way:

```
List<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> myList = new ArrayList<>();

myList.add(new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>("hello", 1));
```

If you need the class to be immutable, you could use the [`AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry.html) class instead.

Answer (score 0):

## Lambdas

Lambda expressions can't non-funtional interfaces. From the [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/FunctionalInterface.html):

> Conceptually, a functional interface has exactly one abstract method.

You won't be able to solve this using lambdas.

## Your actual problem

I think you misunderstand what interfaces are, you can't "add an interface to a collection", you can only add instances of classes that implement an interface. What you currently have is an anonymous class, but it's still a a separete class.